# Modern Literate Programming Tool?

Tags: tools, literate-programming

***Author's Note:***  I'd have posted this to [the 'Software Recommendations' Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) if I'd seen any questions posted about literate-programming software when I did a cursory search there, but I didn't, so here I am…

---

I've been meaning to do some literate programming in the near future, so I did a Google search for it and came upon [this web page of tool recommendations](http://www.literateprogramming.com/tools.html), which at first looked like a good listing.  Upon further inspection, however, my initial impressions of it proved to be somewhat rushed and naïve, as it doesn't exactly seem to state unequivocally which of the tools it lists is the most standard, commonly accepted best practice, or most modern I should work with.  From what I've read around the Web so far, the original WEB was for Pascal and CWEB was for C, but both are obsolete.
     Neither of these would help me, though, since I need something that works with C++, specifically that language's 2011, 2014, and upcoming 2017 revisions.  *That* consideration, therefore, left `noweb` to me as a prominent option.  I was going to use it, but then, alas, I discovered to my chagrin that it, *too*, is deemed obsolete, at least by the watermark on [its CTAN listing](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/noweb), and, according to [its homepage](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/noweb/index.html), has not seen a new release for over *six years!*  Given *this* unpleasant surprise, can anybody recommend me a more modern literate-programming tool or toolchain usable with LaTeX that is still seeing developer maintenance to use?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are not really on-topic as they usually do not revolve around an abstract issue.  Instead, [describe the problem](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and what has been done so far to solve it.  Also, this is a general programming question.  Please ask this in an answerable form on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: There are people on this site who use CWEB and answer [questions about it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cweb). It's not obsolete (Knuth still uses it every week, he says). I think `noweb` is still in use too. Not all software needs new versions every year or even decade (consider TeX). In practice there are as many literate-programming tools/environments as programmers trying literate programming. I have had some success with org-mode and tangle, though I haven't used it with LaTeX: in some sense, producing typeset (for paper) listings of source code is itself obsolete.

Comment: @HenriMenke:  Very well; can this question be moved to [the 'Software Recommendations' Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), then?  I think that might be a better idea since I might get a similar response to the one I encountered here on Stack Overflow.  (I'll have to make an edit to get rid of my question's header, since such a move would make it irrelevant/non-applicable, but I can do that.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR:  Sure, but TeX and LaTeX are still having engines that _implement_ them get maintained, whereas CWEB's and `noweb`'s bits appear to be slowly rotting due to neglect (though perhaps not _nearly_ as quickly as those of _other_ software,) even though they might still, in _practice_, be usable.  `noweb` might still be my best since I wasn't satisfied by the Markdown-based system(s) I('ve) tried, but, personally, I would prefer to use something that still has active, official maintainer support and like how flexible LaTeX is as a typesetting system.  …

Comment: @RandomDSdevel No, unfortunately we cannot do this for you.  We can only migrate questions between TeX.SX and Meta TeX.SX.  So you have to sign up on SoftwareRecs.SX and ask the question again.  But you can essentially copy and paste.

Comment: …Even then, however, I'm really only wanting to get PDFs or other text-friendly files of a suitably rich format out of all of this.  Also, you say there are a lot of literate-programming systems, but I haven't really seen that many beyond the ones mentioned in the reference I originally linked to in my question, so where have you found more of them?

Comment: @HenriMenke:  Wait, I thought you could transfer questions between _any_ Stack Exchange…

Comment: @RandomDSdevel Nope, the dialog only offers Meta ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAb1k.png)).

Comment: @HenriMenke:  Huh, I could have _sworn_ there was a way to move things around more extensively than that, as I've had it used on at least one of my own questions by another user _before…_  Guess I'll just have to copy and paste like you said, then.

Comment: Knuth is still making updates to cweb, e.g. cweb 3.70 is less than a month old.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR:  Oh, huh, cool; I didn't see any mention of that version on [CWEB's Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CWEB).  Well, maybe I'll look into using that, then, if `noweb` doesn't pan out and CWEB supports C++11, C++14, and C++17 (the last one in anticipation of its final release later this year.)

Comment: Just edited my question to clarify that I'm looking for this kind of language support.

Comment: One of the pages on using org-mode for literate programming is [here](http://www.howardism.org/Technical/Emacs/literate-programming-tutorial.html). (The page thinks that noweb is by Knuth rather than Norman Ramsey, but otherwise ok.) I have used it to export to HTML; exporting to LaTeX should be possible too. [And IMO you won't find a “most standard, commonly accepted best practice, or most modern” tool for literate programming as there's basically no literate-programming community; it's just a few eccentric individuals trying to program in this unusual way. :-) But it's worthwhile… good luck]

Comment: @ShreevatsaR:  OK, thanks, but I'm…not very accustomed to using Emacs even though I have it installed, to put it mildly&thinsp;—&thinsp;to be honest, I prefer `nano` as a command-line text editor.  Also, the lack of a community consolidated around literate programming seems to me like it's almost a shame, as having one would be _very_ useful for novices like myself.  (I _do_ agree that the enterprise appears 'worthwhile,' as you've put it, though!  Thanks for the encouragement, too!)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR:  I haven't grown dissatisfied with `noweb` yet, but I see that the latest version of CWEB available in CTAN (and thus from TeX Live) is v3.64b…unless that's just being reported wrong?  And v3.70 seems to be quite hard to find via Google, so maybe this should get fixed…?  (I'd do it myself, but it's not my package and I've never uploaded anything to CTAN.)

Comment: Latest versions of CWEB handle C++, dunno how well . But it is TeX (not LaTeX!) only...